# SQL Server change tracking: how to apply changes manually?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, change-tracking

I have a database with change tracking turned on for all of tables (about 200 tables).

How can I tell SQL Server that I want to apply changes, which are tracked already?

Option with turning change tracking off and then on is not suitable - it spends too much time.

Comment: I'm using 2008 R2 and I'm talking about change tracking, not CDC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Change tracking gives you the needed info - what rows have been inserted, deleted, updated - but I don't see any "automatic" way to apply all those changes to a target database. You get the info needed - but it's up to you to write the synchronization code

Comment: @marc_s: unfortunately, "automatic" way exists, it defined by retention period for database and doing exactly what I want: cleans up change tracking tables... But I need a way to do the same manually, like .NET DataSet.ApplyChanges method.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the "retention" only clears out entries from the change tracking tables - it doesn't **apply** those to any target DB. So what are you looking for: actually **applying** the changes that the change tracking shows you to a second database, or just clearing out the change tracking tables?

Comment: @marc_s, sorry, my question isn't clear. I mean "apply changes" in terms of .NET DataSet.AcceptChanges or Entity Framework ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges methods. They clean change tracking information and reset their entries state to "unchanged". In fact, I need the same functionality from SQL Server change tracking system: any command, which will clear change tracking tables and reset rows state to "unchanged" without removing tracking tables and other tracking stuff.